# Triming and creating a text ellipsis in Javascript based NOT on the number of characters but the number of line breaks

Tags: javascript, facebook, text, trim, ellipsis

I want to program a function that takes in some text and makes a trim on it based on the number of line breaks it has, I want it to trim and place "... Read more" after it hits 6 line breaks, sorta like what Facebook does with comments and wall posts.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I fear this question gets closed if you don't post your own effort.

Comment: I have thought of counting till the the 6th line break, getting the string position there from there onwards I want to trim and save the rest of the text in another variable, What i don't know is.. how to get that string position in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lastIndex property of a global regular expression.

```
var str= 'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\n',
rx=  /((.+\n+){3})/g,
m= rx.exec(str),
cut= rx.lastIndex;
if(cut){
    first3lines= m[1].replace(/\s+$/, '...');
    remainder= str.substring(cut);
}
else{
    first3lines= str;
    remainder= '';
}


alert('first 3 lines:\n'+first3lines+'\n\nremainder:\n'+remainder);
/*  returned value:

first 3 lines:
one
two
three...

remainder:
four
five
six

*/
```

Comment: This works surprizingly well, but how would I write this regex if the breaks were not "\n" but instead "<br>" or <br /> or perhaps /rn

Answer (score 0):

This might be of interest : http://blog.mattschwarz.me/post/2688505800/introducing-clamp-js

Comment: Did not turn out to be very nice, it does not really work in anything other than webkit

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to give you this link http://reusablebits.com/post/2980974411/clamp-js-v0-2-explanations-and-performance-updates. Though it can use webkit specifics it does not have to.